# Rewrite query to prevent only_full_group_by error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-5.7

I have the following query:

```
SELECT f.flight_number, f.flight_date, f.airport, a.iata, a.iso3166 AS airport_country_code, air.icao
        FROM flights_database f
        LEFT JOIN airlines air ON air.name = f.airline
        JOIN airports a ON f.airport = a.airportNameClean
        WHERE f.flight_date
        BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        GROUP by f.flight_date, f.airport, f.flight_number, a.iata
        ORDER by f.airport, f.flight_number
```

Now I have upgraded MysQL and the `only_full_group_by setting` is activated.
This query no longer works in this form:

```
Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'air.ICAO' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Of course I could disable this setting, but I do understand this setting was introduced for a reason. Simply adding `icao` to the `GROUP BY` clause introduces different results.

How can I rewrite this query to achieve the same behavior with this setting enabled?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are several icao's? Can't you simply do max(icao), or min(icao)?

Comment: @jarlh actually this works (MAX), hadn't even thought that you can apply that to varchars. Seems to work great. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply do `max(icao)`?

```
SELECT f.flight_number, f.flight_date, f.airport, a.iata, a.iso3166 AS airport_country_code, max(air.icao)
        FROM flights_database f
        LEFT JOIN airlines air ON air.name = f.airline
        JOIN airports a ON f.airport = a.airportNameClean
        WHERE f.flight_date
        BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        GROUP by f.flight_date, f.airport, f.flight_number, a.iata
        ORDER by f.airport, f.flight_number
```

Comment: Less hack than before anyway! Now you get a defined result for that column.